# how to get contact photo URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working with Android Contact ContentProvider. I have a *Phone Number* and I need to get the *URI* of the *Photo* of the contact associated with this phone number. How can I do it???

I know I can get the *raw data* of the photo and build an *InputStream*, but I dont want the input  stream, I need the *URI*.

EDIT: Originally I'm using following code to fetch contact info

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNo));
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, details, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 12):

To get the conatct id using the phone number use the following code:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;

public String fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
        Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,
        new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID },
        null, null, null);

    String contactId = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactId;
  }
```

and use the contact id obtained to get the contatc photo URI. Use the following code for getting photo URI:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;

public Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    try {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                    + "="
                    + contactId
                    + " AND "

                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                    + "='"
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                    + "'", null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return null; // no photo
        }
        } else {
        return null; // error in cursor process
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
  }
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor when you're done or you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: Also be sure to include the READ_CONTACTS permission in your app's Manifest.

Comment: This getPhotoUri proc is totally wrong in every possible way... DO NOT USE IT... You need to check the existance of the uri too..  Answer should be deleted.. If you need the uri read the PHOTO_URI or PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI from a content provider for valid URIs!

Comment: @xnagyg It's very easy to tell what not to do and what should be done without any example. Please provide your solution.

Answer (score 9):

This solution demonstrates how to get an image from a user contact and then display it in an `ImageView`.

```
ImageView profile  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);                 
Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(Contact_Id));
InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),my_contact_Uri);            
BufferedInputStream buf =new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
profile.setImageBitmap(my_btmp);
```

Comment: The code is missing "buf" in BufferedInputStream buf =new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);

Comment: Also, you can directly set the Uri to an imageView (using imageView.setImageURI(uri) instead of having to convert to Bitmap yourself.

Comment: @paul_sns how about storing it into database? can i use the uri or the bitmap link?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code from [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html).

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
return Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `PHOTO_URI` by `NUMBER` just use following code also you can use _ID.

```
 public static String getContactPhoto(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactImage= null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactImage= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));
    }

    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final boolean IS_HONEYCOMB = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    String phoneNumber = "+1 416 385 7805";
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            IS_HONEYCOMB ? ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI : ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            };
    Cursor cursor =
            contentResolver.query(
                    uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long contactId = cursor.getLong(0);
        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(1);
        String thumbnailUri = cursor.getString(2);           
        cursor.close();
    }
```

So now if sdk is honeycomb or higher u have thumbnail uri of the contact.
Or you can construct a lookup uri like this:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
```

P.S. If you already know **contact id** and/or **lookup key** you can construct a Uri from string:

lookup: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/{lookup key}/{contact id}`
thumbnail: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/{contact id}/photo`

So it's better to cache these values.