# retrieving photo and name from contacts in android

Tags: android, contacts

With my present code I am getting only the contact number. But I want to get `contact's name and contact's photo path`. Have tried many codes by googling, but I am not able to get it done. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738363/1592160) too, but got `FileNotFoundException`. Can someone please help me achieve that by adding code snippets to the below code?

```
public void getContact(View view)
{

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
         intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

             if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                if (uri != null) {
                    Cursor c = null;
                    try {
                        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                null, null, null);

                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String phoneNumber = c.getString(0);
                            int type = c.getInt(1);      
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         }
```

Answer (score 11):

This code traverses all contacts and gets their first name, last name and photo as a bitmap:

```
Cursor cursor = App
            .getInstance()
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            // get firstName & lastName
            Cursor nameCur = App.getInstance().getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                    + " = ? AND "
                                    + StructuredName.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?",
                            new String[] {
                                    StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                    Long.valueOf(id).toString() }, null);
            if (nameCur != null) {
                if (nameCur.moveToFirst()) {

                    String displayName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (displayName == null) displayName = "";

                    String firstName  = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                    if (firstName == null) firstName = "";
                    Log.d("--> ", firstName.length()>0?firstName:displayName);

                    String middleName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
                    if (middleName == null) middleName = "";

                    String lastName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                    if (lastName == null) lastName = "";

                    lastName = middleName + (middleName.length()>0?" ":"") + lastName;

                    Log.d("--> ", lastName);
                }
                nameCur.close();
            }

            Bitmap photo = null;

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(App.getContext().getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(id)));

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                }

                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("--> ", photo);
        }
    }

    if (cursor != null) { cursor.close(); }
```

You also needs this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the method am using to get contact photo, number and name but am dong this from a Fragment.

**1** Set the permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**2** Declare a constant:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT = 1;
```

**3** In my app the user is required to choose a phone contact by clicking on a button. So in the onClick() method I do this:

```
contactChooserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
          ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);

        }
    });
```

**4** Add the methods to retrieve photo, name, and number:

```
private String retrieveContactNumber() {

    String contactNumber = null;

    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.e(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        phoneNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.e(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    return contactNumber;

}

 //Retrieve name
 private void retrieveContactName() {

    String contactName = null;

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
        // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        personName = contactName;
    }

    cursor.close();

    Log.e(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

}

//Retrieve photo (this method gets a large photo, for thumbnail follow the link below)
public void retrieveContactPhoto() {

    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactID));
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd =
                getActivity().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
        photoAsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fd.createInputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

finally, in your onActivityForResult method, do this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
    try {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
            uriContact = data.getData();
            personPhoneTextField.setText(retrieveContactNumber()); 
//the method retrieveContactNumber returns the contact number, 
//so am displaying this number in my EditText after getting it.
//Make your other methods return data of 
//their respective types (Bitmap for photo)

  retrieveContactPhoto();
  retrieveContactName();


        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

That's it.For Activities, take a look at this [Android: Get Contact Details (ID, Name, Phone, Photo)](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/7058235) on Github