# How to get writable DocumentFile Uri from a Media real path?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a situation in Lollipop where I have:

1. Directory tree (`DocumentFile`) which is granted from user.
2. A collection of audio files that need to modify retrieved from media provider.

   ```
   Uri mediaUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
       "45");
   ```

Then, how to write a stream into one of those files?

I think, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514269/615025 gives a work around. Copy bytes of the file to cache directory, do modification on the temporary file and then copy the bytes back to the original file.

[DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) is a new mechanism which allows us to modify files in Lollipop. It is not the same case with this post [how to get contact photo URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738192/how-to-get-contact-photo-uri)
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get content uri from file path in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: nope, not a duplicate. Completely different topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can open an outputStream directly from a Uri using `ContentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri)`
For example,

```
OutputStream fos;
fos = new BufferedOutputStream(context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri));
```

Optionally, `openOutputStream` takes a string to specify mode.
i.e

```
openOutputStream(uri, "w");
```

to write or

```
openOutputStream(uri, "wa");
```

to append.